# PHP: Navigating through subdirectories

Tags: php, html

Consider the following directory tree:

```
/root
    page1.php
    menu.php
    /subdir
        page2.php
```

Here, menu.php is a navigation menu:

```
<div class="cssmenu">
    <li><a href="link to page 1">page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link to page 2">page 2</a></li>
</div>
```

Both page1.php and page2.php invoke menu.php through the include function:

```
<?php include "path to menu.php"?>
```

However, when code is summoned through the include function, relative links in the navigation menu become ill-defined. How should I define links in the navigation menu as to be properly rendered in a browser? Preferably, I'd like this to be independent of the absolute path of /root, so that I may render my site through my localmachine.

Comment: create a base_url constant and prepend it to your links. This constant should change with the environment

Comment: @Petah to broke all other links...

Answer (score 0):

You may start link with `/` (slash). It means address in current site from root of the site. See example for clarity

```
<a href="/link_from_root_of_the_site">Link</a>
```

Example: [Badges](/help/badges/) (`<a href="/help/badges/">Badges</a>`)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like for the links to be independent of which particular server the site is on (so that I can render it on my desktop without any hard coding).

Comment: @user2499604, if  you using any webserver on your machine it will ok, link will be relative to the root of current site (for ex. `http://localhost/`)

Comment: He means start the link with a forward slash. That means even if your root changes, it will still look at the same spot from the root wherever that may be.